# ng build --prod --env=prod doesn't minify output js files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm building Angular4 app and want to minify output bundles. I use following comand to compile the app

```
npm run ng build --prod --env=prod
```

But resulted bundle files are not minified.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Look through this blog : http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

Comment: I need a deault way..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it might not be necessary to say that you want production twice, I'd rather use this:

npm run ng build --env=prod